# Jquery error() working in chrome and IE but not firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am trying to figure out why this jQuery is working fine in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox. What it should be doing (and is doing in chrome and IE) is looping through each of the li's in the ul and seeing if the IMG src throws an error. If it does the li is removed.

```
$('ul.community-properties li').each(function() {
    $('li IMG').on('error', function() {
       $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

I have also tried

```
$('ul.community-properties li').each(function() {
    $('li IMG').error(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

If anyone has a more efficient way or a way to get this to work in all browsers that would be great.

Here is the html structure

```
<ul class="community-properties">
    <li>
     <img src="{tag_community property1_value}" />
     <div class="item-link"><a href="{tag_community property1 url}">View Property Details</a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="{tag_community property2_value}" />
     <div class="item-link"><a href="{tag_community property2 url}">View Property Details</a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="{tag_community property3_value}" />
     <div class="item-link"><a href="{tag_community property3 url}">View Property Details</a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="{tag_community property4_value}" />
     <div class="item-link"><a href="{tag_community property4 url}">View Property Details</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When are you binding it?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: you don't really need the each there, in fact the `li IMG` selector inside it is horribly inefficient as it will target every li with an image inside it in the DOM every time.

Comment: nope, check with firebug and get nothing. When I inspect the code in firefox it shows the event is being run but for some reason it isnt executing the code in the error function

Comment: @Rooster How would I loop through all the li's in the ul without each?

Comment: @MichaelMcCoy `$('ul.community-properties li li IMG').error(...` woudl be a better way for starters, can't say more without seeing html structure.

Comment: @Rooster added the html structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the image was loaded already

```js
window.setTimeout( function() { //added delay to make sure that onerror already has run. 

$('ul.community-properties li img').one('error', function() {  //bind the error event to the images
    $(this).parent().remove();
}).filter( function() {  //check to see if an image was loaded from the cache as broken (or if onerror fired before set)
    return (this.complete && (this.naturalWidth===0 || this.naturalWidth===undefined));  
}).trigger("error");  //fire the error event


},1000);  //Broken images should hide after one second
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="community-properties">
    <li>
     <img src="{tag_community property1_value}" />
     <div class="item-link"><a href="{tag_community property1 url}">View Property Details</a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UyY6HH5.gif" />
     <div class="item-link"><a href="{tag_community property2 url}">View Property Details</a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="{tag_community property3_value}" />
     <div class="item-link"><a href="{tag_community property3 url}">View Property Details</a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="{tag_community property4_value}" />
     <div class="item-link"><a href="{tag_community property4 url}">View Property Details</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```